# VBA-variable in cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

Just wondering if anyone can help me with the syntax of this. 
The value of `F14` is 12.

I want to select column C and the row number will be the number that is in cell `F14`.

```
Range("f14").Value = x
Dim x As Integer

range("cx").select
```

Comment: Try this one liner:  `Cells(Range("F14").Value, 3).Select`

Comment: ... or `range("C" & x).select`

Answer (score 3):

```
Range("cx").select
```

You need to understand the fundamentals here - in VBA anything you put in double quotes is a *string literal*, so `"cx"` is just that: a *string literal*.

Yes, the `Range` function (which is implicitly referring to the active sheet, so it's like calling `ActiveSheet.Range`, which isn't ideal) wants a `String` parameter to specify an address - but `x` is an `Integer` local variable, not a string literal.

First things first, stick `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

Then, declare your variables *before* you use them.

Now, you need to "grab" the value of F14 and store it in `x` - to do that you need to *assign* `x`. Your assignment operation is reversed - you're assigning `F14`'s value to X, when you intend to do it the other way around; flip that around:

```
Dim x As Integer
x = ActiveSheet.Range("F14").Value
```

Now *if all goes well* you have the value of `F14` stored in X. If the cell doesn't contain a numeric value you'll run into problems for which you'll find plenty of solutions on this site if you bother searching a bit.

So `x` has the numeric value `12`, and you need a `String` that says `C12` - you need to *concatenate* the string literal `"C"` with the value of `x`. VBA gives you the *string concatenation operator* for that: `&`.

```
Dim theAddress As String
theAddress = "C" & CStr(x)
```

The `CStr` function isn't really needed, but it makes it explicit that you're converting `x` (a number) to a `String`. If you don't do the conversion explicitly, VBA will try to do it implicitly for you (and that's not always a good thing).

So `theAddress` is now a *string variable* that contains the value `"C12"` (assuming `x` was `12`).

Give it to that `Range` function:

```
Range(theAddress).Select
```

Hope it helps.